# bep20 web3 send tokens between accounts example

Tags: binance, cryptocurrency, bsc, bep20

someone can provide how to transfer bep20 token on BSC testnet between accounts. I tried in different ways but have a problem
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code. Include the code in the question itself via a [mcve]. This includes error messagesa nd log/trace data as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sender address, stored in the `accountFrom.address` value, doesn't hold enough BNB to pay for the gas fees related to the token transfer.

**Solution:** Fund the address so that it has at least 0.00054187 BNB *(= 54,187 gas units, times 10 gwei as the gas price)* on the testnet to cover the fees for this transaction.